# The Hosting History OS is unknown in the www.netcraft.com

Tags: linux, ip

I test a website's url(`www.ccguitar.cn`) in `www.netcraft.com`, that can get a site's information.

But the Hosting History's OS is unknown.

[image]

If I test the `www.tencent.com`, there will show the Linux OS in it.[image]

There is two question here:

1.Why the first site(www.ccguitar.cn) can not analysis the OS?
 2.Why the second site(www.tencent.com)'s ip address keeps changing several times per month?

Comment: Oddly enough, the first question can be on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netcraft does not know the history of the operating system, as some web servers can be configured for security purposes, not to give information/strings that are not deemed appropriate.

For instance the Apache web server can be configured, in Debian, in the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf` as:

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

The security configuration is also normally enabled by default in Apache, otherwise you would have to run:

```
sudo a2enconf security
```

From the comments of the file:

> ServerTokens: This directive configures what you return as the Server HTTP response
>   Header. The default is 'Full' which sends information about the
>   OS-Type and compiled in modules.
>   Set to one of:  Full | OS | Minimal | Minor | Major | Prod
>   where
>   Full conveys the most information, and Prod the least.
>
> ServerSignature: Optionally add a line containing the server version and virtual host
>   name to server-generated pages (internal error documents, FTP
>   directory listings, mod_status and mod_info output etc., but not CGI
>   generated documents or custom error documents).
>   Set to "EMail" to also
>   include a mailto: link to the ServerAdmin.
>   Set to one of:  On | Off |
>   EMail

As for IP address changes, a floating IP in a long time may mean it changed ISP/hosting providers. 
More frequent IP changes might mean the site is hosted in an residential ISP/home grade connection, *or* it might mean the web server name is working with several IP addresses.

As a test, with `ServerTokens Prod` and `ServerSignature Off`:

```
$telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 09 Jun 2017 17:18:08 GMT
Server: Apache
```

Without that security configuration, you would have otherwise:

```
$telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 09 Jun 2017 17:23:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) SVN/1.8.10 mod_jk/1.2.37 OpenSSL/1.0.2j
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why the second site(www.tencent.com)'s ip address is Keep a changing

DNS load balancing.  There are several servers, presumably because this is a very busy system.  In this case it is easily visible (in others, the DNS might have returned a different, single IP each time).

```
$ dig www.tencent.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.4-P8-RedHat-9.10.4-5.P8.fc25 <<>> www.tencent.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47598
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 10, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.tencent.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.tencent.com.    60  IN  CNAME   upfile.wj.qq.com.cloud.tc.qq.com.
upfile.wj.qq.com.cloud.tc.qq.com. 600 IN CNAME  ssd.tcdn.qq.com.
ssd.tcdn.qq.com.    20  IN  A   203.205.158.55
ssd.tcdn.qq.com.    20  IN  A   203.205.151.212
ssd.tcdn.qq.com.    20  IN  A   203.205.158.34
ssd.tcdn.qq.com.    20  IN  A   203.205.158.56
ssd.tcdn.qq.com.    20  IN  A   203.205.158.53
ssd.tcdn.qq.com.    20  IN  A   203.205.158.54
ssd.tcdn.qq.com.    20  IN  A   203.205.151.211
ssd.tcdn.qq.com.    20  IN  A   203.205.158.35

;; Query time: 787 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.8.1#53(172.16.8.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 09 18:17:48 BST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 238
```